# A question is appearing twice in the "No Answers" tab

Tags: bug

In questions tagged [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress), under [the "No Answers" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/wordpress?tab=noanswers), on the first page, I have noticed a bug: a question is duplicated.

[image: duplicated post]

The question is not posted twice, it is the same question.

Comment: Of course. It's a ninja question. It's shadow-stepping, the opacity change just did not catch up.

Comment: 'ninja question'?

Comment: *Ninja form data?* Sorry, that was just a pun. I do that sometimes when I upvote a bug report.

Comment: okay, that makes sense :)

Comment: It resolved it self because we looked at it?

Comment: @rene It is a combination of Shinobi-iri and Inton-jutsu http://www.warriorsandlegends.com/japanese-warriors/ninja-warriors/ninja-warrior-skills/ Do you see anything else?

Comment: No, I still see this question duplicated in that list. I also see ["Woocommerce overridden not work after Administrator logged in"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36308178/woocommerce-overridden-not-work-after-administrator-logged-in) duplicated in that list. Don't see any others though.

Comment: No repo for me.  Win 7 with latest chrome.

Comment: Repo on Win10 on IE, not sure what version

Comment: Repo? Isn't it repro?

Comment: I see the Ninja question twice on Win 10 latest Chrome, but not the Woocommerce.